# lmer three-way interaction with categorical variables shows both levels of a predictor

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interaction

I am comparing (scaled) Hz values for two vowels (Vowel A, Vowel B) of the same speakers from two countries (Australia, England) in three situations (Sit1, Sit2, Sit3). I am investigating whether the speakers produce significantly different Hz values for the vowels, and whether there is variation depending on situation (within-subject) and home country (between-subject). I have used sum coding on my categorical variables.

The problem is, when I run the model, my summary shows strange interactions. My main effects and two-way interactions look perfectly normal, but in my three-way interaction I suddenly have Vowel A (i.e., the reference level) specified in interactions separately from Vowel B.

I am running pairwise comparisons using the *emmeans* package in order to interpret my interactions, but I'm worried that there is something wrong with my model that makes the reference level of VowelType show up as a separate interaction in the summary. When I run a largely identical model with the same predictors except for different vowels, this does not happen.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
mod <- lmer(DVscaled ~ voweltype + situation  + country + 
voweltype:situation + voweltype:country + 
voweltype:situation:country + (1 | speaker), data=datafile)

summary(mod)

                       Estimate   Std.E  df     t        p
(Intercept)            0.021668   0.03   209   1.411    0.3340 
Sit2                   0.201966   0.05   602   7.285    <2e-16 ***
Sit3                  -0.290173   0.08   602   -12.889  <2e-16 ***
VowelB                 0.787753   0.08   602   44.632   <2e-16 ***
English                0.093690   0.09   602   4.732    5.15e-06 ***

Sit2:VowelB            0.339263   0.03   602   10.331   <2e-16 ***
Sit3:VowelB           -0.058265   0.03   602   -1.436   0.1309 
VowelB:English        -0.159330   0.04   602   -9.201   <2e-16 ***

Sit2:VowelB:England    0.029816   0.04   602   0.871    0.4781 
Sit3:VowelB:England    0.027348  0.04   602   0.894    0.4145 
Sit2:VowelA:England   -0.070819   0.04   602   -2.011   0.0450 * 
Sit3:VowelA:England    0.049872   0.04   602   1.069    0.3060
```

Answer (score 2):

Your model seems strange - it misses the two-way interaction between situation and country, that is, situation:country. Why not specify your model like this:

```
lmer(DVscaled ~ voweltype * situation * country + 
                (1|speaker), data = datafile)
```

to make sure you are automatically capturing all two-way and three-way interactions? Alternatively, specify your model as you did but by including *all* two-way and three-way interactions.

Comment: Thank you, that actually worked perfectly! I got the same results just without the odd lines that include the interaction with Vowel A specified.

(The reason the model was specified this way was because I also had some more main main effects that were not included in interactions based on the model comparisons, but it seems that somehow the way I defined the model made the summary strange.)

Comment: Great! I’m glad this worked. 